# SQL Server - Add conditional inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I'm new to database development and I've a stored procedure where I need to do some INNER JOINs to tables only when a condition is met. Below is a shorter version of my complex query.

```
IF (testFunction(@UserId)) = 0 
  select C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes from Client C 
    where C.Id = @ClientId
    group by C.AwardId, C.ProgramName...
ELSE
  select C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes from Client C
    INNER JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
    INNER JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
         where C.Id = @ClientId
         group by C.AwardId, C.ProgramName...
END
```

Basically, its the same SELECT query in both "IF" and "ELSE" except that I need to do an inner join on 2 tables when the IF condition is not met. Instead of repeating the query in both "IF" and "ELSE", is there a way to make it a single query without going for a Dynamic query?

Thank You!

Comment: I presume the joins do additional filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional `WHERE` criteria and `LEFT JOIN` to filter conditionally:

```
SELECT C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes 
FROM Client C
LEFT JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
LEFT JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
WHERE C.Id = @ClientId
 AND (   testFunction(@UserId) = 0
      OR (testFunction(@UserId) <> 0 AND URE.AwardID IS NOT NULL AND UR.ID IS NOT NULL))
GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramName
```

Comment: Perfect. It works!! Thank you so much! I just changed the WHERE condition to  WHERE (   testFunction(@UserId) = 0 
       OR (testFunction(@UserId) <> 0 AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId )). I'm getting the same results. Please let me know if this is incorrect.

Comment: I think that makes sense, I used the `IS NOT NULL` to ensure it filters to joining records when it is `0`, but that might not be needed, if your results are correct then that's the important bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your query right, you want to display all field even `CDPUserID` is not exist or `0` right? You just need `FULL JOIN` in second join :

```
SELECT C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes FROM Client C
INNER JOIN UserRoleEntity URE ON C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
FULL JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
     WHERE C.Id = @ClientId
     GROUP BY C.AwardId, C.ProgramName...
```

Comment: Where is my condition (testFunction(@UserId)) = 0 being checked anywhere in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Use a OR and EXISTS() in the where condition

```
select C.AwardId, C.ProgramName, Count(ClientId) as Intakes from Client C
where 
    (testFunction(@UserId)) = 0 
    OR 
    (
      EXISTS
      (
        SELECT * FROM UserRoleEntity URE INNER JOIN UserRole UR ON URE.UserRoleId = UR.Id AND UR.CDPUserId = @UserId
        WHERE C.AwardId = URE.EntityId 
      ) 
      AND C.Id = @ClientId
    )
group by C.AwardId, C.ProgramName...
```